# Override interface type but keeping the shape with nested objects

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have an interface I use to define the shape of a NoSQL document schema. This contains strings, arrays, nested objects, etc. For example, I have something like this:

```js
interface IStudentSchema {
  name: string;
  age: string;
  foo: {
    a: number;
    b: [number, number];
    c: string;
  }
}
```

I want to create another interface which maintains the same shape, but the type of each values to be replaced by a certain interface (except when the type is object), For example, I want something like this below. Please note that it also maintains the original type, and uses it as a generic.

```js
interface IStudentSchemaFieldInfo {
  name: ISchemaField<string>;
  age: ISchemaField<string>;
  foo: {
    a: ISchemaField<number>;
    b: ISchemaField<[number, number]>;
    c: ISchemaField<string>;
  }
}
```

Is there a way to do this so that I get a *compile-time warning* if I modify the original schema interface? So far, I had to manually keep them in sync.

I can almost do this there are no nested objects by using `Record<keyof IStudentSchema, ISchemaField>`, but this still also does not get the generics to be specified for the `ISchemaField` inteface. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you can do this by *extending* the child interface. I flipped the definition by the way, the Schema has the `ISchemaField` definition.

```js
interface MysqlObject<T> {
  method<T>(): boolean;
}

type ISchemaField<T> = T | MysqlObject<T>;

interface IStudentSchema {
  name: ISchemaField<string>;
  age: ISchemaField<string>;
  foo: {
    a: ISchemaField<number>;
    b: ISchemaField<[number, number]>;
    c: ISchemaField<string>;
  }
}

interface IStudent extends IStudentSchema {
  name: string;
  age: string;
  foo: {
    a: number;
    b: [number, number];
    c: string;
  }
}
```

This maintains the shape of the base interface and will throw a compile-time error if it's changed.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work if I add or delete a field from the IStudentSchema or StudentSchema as I don't get any warning, and it compiles fine. They must be kept in sync.

Comment: @CookieMonster what you're requesting is that type checking is to be done _both_ ways. This would mean that both types depend on each other, which is a circular reference and not allowed in typescript. The ideal solution would be to generic-generics or higher-order types, but this is not implemented in the language yet. See this github issue for details https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213